# How to avoid running out of space on App Engine due to Libraries?

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine, google-cloud-shell

My current workflow on Google's App Engine looks like the following commands:

```
cd <my_project_directory>
git pull
cd <my_specific_project>
virtualenv --python python3 ~/envs/aws99
source ~/envs/aws99/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It is at this point that, if I have done this enough times since my last removal of $HOME, I will get:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

This is because my libraries have used up all available space in my home directory.

My workflow is very inefficient because, to resolve this, I delete the whole drive and start from scratch (cloning git again)

```
sudo rm -rf $HOME
```

Although I can instead install requirements to new temp directories with more space, I'd like to just overwrite my existing requirements or avoid continuously adding to the space in my home directory until I have to erase it again.

What is the proper way this workflow should go? Can I issue a better requirements command for this? If not, is there a less nuclear option to clean up all libraries in one command instead of having to go to a specific directory and clear up space file-by-file?

Comment: I understand that you work in Cloud Shell. It has [limited resources](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works) so I don't think you can do much here except just deleting outdated stuff when you out of disk space.